Get parent relationships via sObject Describe
I have a question about how to get information about relationships from Salesforce.  For example, let's consider the Parent relationship on Account.
I know I can get information via childRelationships.  That will give me the Id field ParentId and the childrelationship name ChildAccounts.
However, I'm interesting in getting the parent relationship name from the API, which is named Parent.
I looked in fields, but couldn't find a field called "Parent" there.
Where can I get that relationship via sobject describe on the REST API?
PS: the reason I'm interested in this, is that I'm working on a complicated data migration and would like to leverage all the relationship fields when importing records via the Bulk API 2.0.

I figured it out.
You can get the parent relationship information via the referenceTo and relationshipName in the node for the parentId field.
